# Hibernate No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: java, hibernate, classloader

I have an Eclipse plugin that uses Hibernate. The Hibernate jar that I use is part of the JBOSS Tools plugin that I installed. I migrated to Eclipse 4.2 Juno and updated my JBOSS Tools for Juno as well.

Now my problem is, my current code doesn't work anymore. To me, it seems a ClassLoader issue between HIbernate and my Application.

I have code that loads a dynamic JDBC driver. I load the jar using a Class that extends the **URLClassLoader** and register a fake driver using **DriverManager**. Next I build the **SessionFactory**, then the get the **Session**, then the **Transaction**

```
Session hbmSession = mySessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = hbmSession.getTransaction();
```

When I call the

```
DriverManager.getConnection(<my_jdbc_url>,<user>,<pwd>);
```

I was able to get the Connection object back but when I call the Session to beginTransaction() that's where it blows up

```
if (tx == null || !tx.isActive()) {
  tx = hbmSession.beginTransaction();
}
```

and throw this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for    
jdbc:oracle:thin:@190.255.10.10:1521:DBID
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
```

It is weird because it also calls the DriverManager to get the connection. Any clue?

Appreciate your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of providing database connection in Hibernate is using Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory() that returns SessionFactory

The SessionFactory object should be configured as a singleton. It has a static method: getCurrentSession() that returns a hibernate Session.

Important: you need to put a file hibernate.cfg.xml into your classpath.  If you use Eclipse you can put this file into the src folder.

This configuration file should contain hibernate.connection.url, hibernate.connection.username, and hibernate.connection.passsword

There are plenty of examples, i.e. http://manikandanmv.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/hibernate-basics-simple-example/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't have the hibernate.cfg.xml physically but I create it programmatically and put all the db stuff in there. Which I think is fine. My old code works at least for Hibernate 3.4. I updated to Eclipse 4.2 and i think it uses Hibernate 3.6. For some reason, it doesn't work anymore. I guess the problem is Hibernate doesn't see the driver that I dynamically loaded using my ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It looks like JBoss' Hibernatools have their own FakeDelegatingDriver object for clients to use on a separate plugin package. org.hibernate.eclipse.libs I used that instead of my own FakeDriver so I can load dynamic drivers.